# Приходят пустые заявки в Telegram

Tags: php

Вот мой код, не пойму в чем кроется причина. Приходят с различной переодичностью полностью пустые, хотя я захожу на сайт заполняю данные и все доходит как нужно.

```
 <?php
    $name = $_POST['user_name'];
    $telegram = $_POST['user_telegram'];
    $description = $_POST['user_description'];
    $id_user = $_POST['id_user'];
    $token = "";
    $chat_id = "";
    $worker_chat_id = "";
    
    $arr = array(
      'id: ' => $id_user,
      'Name: ' => $name,
      'Telegram: ' => $telegram,
      'Description' => $description
    );
    
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
      $txt .= "<b>".$key."</b> ".$value."%0A";
    };
    
    $arr_worker = array(
      ""=>'Пришла новая заявка',
      'id: ' => $id_user,
    );
    
    foreach($arr_worker as $key => $value) {
      $txt_worker .= "<b>".$key."</b> ".$value."%0A";
    };
    
    $sendToTelegram = fopen("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id}&parse_mode=html&text={$txt}","r");
    
    
    $sendToTelegram_2 = fopen("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$worker_chat_id}&parse_mode=html&text={$txt_worker}","r");
    
    
    if ($sendToTelegram and $sendToTelegram_2) {
      header('Location: /success');
    } else {
      echo "Error";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: Вы удивляетесь, что могут прийти пустые заявки, при этом не ограничиваете отправку пустой формы на сервере. Не надо так...

Comment: Опишите контекст кода, когда и как он используется, в ином случае, данный участок выглядит более или менее корректно.

Comment: Код привязан к форме, в самой форме находятся 3 поля (name, username, details). Когда заполняется заявка в 2 чата телеграм бот присылает данные. В первый чат полностью всю информацию заявки, во второй чат что заявка пришла и id - человека который привел данную заявку. По факту во втором чате это реферальная система, отправляется post запрос https://domain.com?id=@username, и приходит заявка с данным id человека который её привел. Ещё заметил что пустые заявки приходят только во второй чат, в первый ничего не идет.